# Cant upload .csv file into db using php?

Tags: php, mysql

Here is the code, which is written for uploading .csv file using php. but I get an error as

```
 Warning: 
 fopen(excel/) [function.fopen]: 
 failed to open stream: No such file or directory 
 in C:\xampp\htdocs\interfaceasia\dealer_portal\upload\index.php on line 49
```

which is the line

```
if(($handle = fopen("excel/".$fileName , "r")) !== FALSE)
```

Can someone help on what has gone wrong here.

```
 if($_FILES['csvFile']['name']!="")
     {
            $fileName=uploadFile($_FILES['excelFile'],array(".csv"),"excel_file");
        $row=0;
        if(($handle = fopen("excel/".$fileName , "r")) !== FALSE) 
        {
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
            {
                $num = count($data);
                print_r($data);
                $query="INSERT INTO  dealer_tbl(title,firstname,lastname,email,phone)VALUES('".$data[0]."','".$data[1]."','".$data[2]."','".$data[3]."','".$data[4]."')";
                mysql_query($query);
            }
            fclose($handle);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It looks like the file you're trying to open doesn't exist

Comment: Error clearly say, that it is not finding the requested file. i.e. "excel/".$filename. So you should try to print file name and see why script is not finding it.

Comment: do you have a folder called **C:\xampp\htdocs\interfaceasia\dealer_portal\upload\excel** and a file in there ?

Comment: What is the uploadFile function supposed to do? It seems to be supposed to return a file name, but apparently it does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a folder called

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\interfaceasia\dealer_portal\upload\excel
```

and of course you need a file in there

and whats also important, in your line....

```
if(($handle = fopen("excel/".$fileName , "r")) !== FALSE)
```

$filename seems to be empty at all

because error says something like this

```
fopen(excel/)
```

there are some more errors

```
if($_FILES['csvFile']['name']!="")
 {     //___^^^^^^^^____here you have csvFile
        $fileName=uploadFile($_FILES['excelFile'],array(".csv"),"excel_file");
        //____________________________^^^^^^^^^^____here you have excelFile
```

you really should take care the upload befor trying to enhance your script :)

```
if($_FILES['csvFile']['tmp_name']!="")
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['csvFile']['tmp_name'], "excel/myFile.csv");
```